# Use foreign key simply to prevent data insertion? SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

When doing an insert for a table, a foreign key is automatically checked against its parent table to make sure the value exists. If it doesn't exist, the insert fails.

My question is, is it wrong to set a value as a foreign key simply for this data check on insertion?

Some nerdy context of what i'm trying to do:

I'm building a wrestling database to brush up on everything I've forgotten since college. Being a wrestling fan I thought using it as a topic would keep my interest (and it has).

```
Create Table Superstar
(
    Superstar_ID Int Not Null Primary Key Identity (100,1),
    Employee_ID Int Not Null Foreign Key References Employee(Employee_ID),
    Alignment_ID Int Not Null Foreign Key References Alignment(Alignment_ID),
    SuperStar_Name Varchar(50) Not Null,
    SuperStar_Weight Varchar(50) Not Null,
    SuperStar_Height Varchar(50) Not Null,
    Billed_From Varchar(50) Not Null,
    Active Bit Not Null
)

Create Table Title
(
    Title_ID Int Not Null Primary Key Identity(1,1),
    Title_Name Varchar(50) Not Null,
    Title_Description Varchar(50) Not Null,
    **Current_Holder Int Foreign Key References Superstar(Superstar_ID),
    Former_Holder Int Foreign Key References Superstar(Superstar_ID),**
    Active Bit Not Null
)

Create Table Superstar_Title
(
    Superstar_Title_ID Int Not Null Primary Key Identity (1,1),
    Title_ID Int Not Null Foreign Key References Title(Title_ID),
    Superstar_ID Int Not Null Foreign Key References Superstar(Superstar_ID)
)
```

For the 'Title' table, I've set the Current_Holder and Former_Holder fields as foreign keys to check the Superstar table that the Superstar_ID actually exists on insert.

Is this terribly wrong? Using a foreign key simply for the built in check constraint?

Comment: What is "alignment" is it the weight class ? Or the competition class ? (both could change over time)

Answer (score 3):

That's the whole point of having a constraint - to check that the data is consistent. So, no, it's perfectly fine. Actually, it's encouraged - keeps your data integrity, so that you don't get stuff that's being "held" by non-existing people.

**Edit**: What I mean to say by "encouraged" is that, while you should do this, technology enables you not to. If you want to check manually, then you are free not to enforce foreign keys relations in the database. However, you **have** to perform the check somewhere, or otherwise, you will end up with useless data. And since you are brushing up on your SQL skills, then I guess it is best to take advantage of all the capabilities of the RDMBS that you are using.

Comment: Wow that was speedy. Thanks hahaha.

Comment: While it's good to know this is acceptable to do, is this considered best practice?

By definition aren't foreign keys designed to link tables together in some meaningful way? Would something like a trigger or transaction be better for this sort of check?

Or am I really just over-thinking this.

Comment: @Corgalas, While foreign keys do indeed link tables together, such a link is only meaningful if it references actual data in both tables. If you reference a value, which is not there, then the reference is useless. So, the concept of referential integrity was born - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity. In short, yes, this is the best practice, you should be doing this if you want accurate data. Also, see my edit above.